# Laravel Many-to-Many (on the same users table/Model): Query scopes to include related for the specified user

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

Users can block each other. One user can block **many** (other) users, and one user can be blocked by **many** (other) users. 
In `User` model I have these *many-to-many* relationships:

```
/**
 * Get the users that are blocked by $this user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function blockedUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ignore_lists', 'user_id', 'blocked_user_id');
}

/**
 * Get the users that blocked $this user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function blockedByUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ignore_lists', 'blocked_user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

(`ignore_lists` is the pivot table and it has `id`, `user_id`, `'blocked_user_id'` columns)

I want to create the following **Query Scopes**:

**1)** To include users that **are** blocked by the specified user (`$id`):

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include users that are blocked by the specified user.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeAreBlockedBy($query, $id)
{
    // How to do this? :)
}
```

**Example of usage:** `User::areBlockedBy(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();`

**2)** To include users that are **not** blocked by the specified user (`$id`):

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include users that are not blocked by the specified user.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeAreNotBlockedBy($query, $id)
{
    // How to do this? :)
}
```

**Example of usage:** `User::areNotBlockedBy(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();`

**3)** To include users that **blocked** the specified user (`$id`):

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include users that blocked the specified user.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeWhoBlocked($query, $id)
{
    // How to do this? :)
}
```

**Example of usage:** `User::whoBlocked(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();`

**4)** To include users that **did not block** the specified user (`$id`):

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include users that did not block the specified user.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeWhoDidNotBlock($query, $id)
{
    // How to do this? :)
}
```

**Example of usage:** `User::whoDidNotBlock(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();`

---

How would you do this? 
I didn't find anything in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) about this (maybe I missed it).
(I'm using *Laravel 6.x*)

I'm not sure, but I think this could be done in two ways: Using **Left Join** or using *raw queries* in *whereIn*... I may be wrong, but I think the "left join" solution would be better as far as performance is concerned, right? (not sure about this, maybe I'm totally wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join(inner join)` performance is better than `whereIn` subquery.

In MySQL, subselects within the IN clause are re-executed for every row in the outer query, thus creating `O(n^2)`.

I think use `whereHas` and `whereDoesntHave` for query will be more readable.

1) The relationship method `blockedUsers()` has already include users that **are blocked** by the specified `user ($id)`, you can use this method directly:

```php
User::where('id', $id)->first()->blockedUsers();
```

Considerate about applying the `where('verified', 1)` at first, so you can use query like `User::where('verified', 1)->areBlockedBy(auth()->id())`, the scope can be like this:

```php
public function scopeAreBlockedBy($query, $id)
{
    return $query->whereHas('blockedByUsers', function($users) use($id) {
               $users->where('ignore_lists.user_id', $id);
           });
}

// better performance: however, when you apply another where condition, you need to specify the table name ->where('users.verified', 1)
public function scopeAreBlockedBy($query, $id)
{
    return $query->join('ignore_lists', function($q) use ($id) {
               $q->on('ignore_lists.blocked_user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->where('ignore_lists.user_id', $id);
           })->select('users.*')->distinct();
}
```

We use `join` for the second query that will improve the performance because it doesn't need to use `where exists`.

#### Example for 300,000+ records in users table:

Explain the first query `whereHas` which scan `301119+1+1` rows and takes `575ms`:
[image: whereHas explain]
[image: whereHas times]

Explain the second query `join` which scan `3+1` rows and takes `10.1ms`:
[image: Join explain]
[image: Join time]

2) To include users that **are not blocked by** the specified `user ($id)`, you can use `whereDoesntHave` closure like this one:

```php
public function scopeNotBlockedUsers($query, $id)
{
    return $query->whereDoesntHave('blockedByUsers', function($users) use ($id){
           $users->where('ignore_lists.user_id', $id);
     });
}
```

I prefer to use `whereDoesntHave` instead of `leftJoin` here. Because when you use `leftjoin` like this below:

```php
User::leftjoin('ignore_lists', function($q) use ($id) {                                                            
     $q->on('ignore_lists.blocked_user_id', '=', 'users.id') 
       ->where('ignore_lists.user_id', $id);
})->whereNull('ignore_lists.id')->select('users.*')->distinct()->get();
```

Mysql need to create an temporary table for storing **all the users' records** and combine some `ignore_lists`.And then scan these records and find out the records which without `ignore_lists`. `whereDosentHave` will scan **all users** too. For my mysql server, `where not exists` is a little faster than `left join`. Its execution plan seems good. The performance of these two queries are not much different.
[image: whereDoesntHave explain]
[image: left join is null]

For `whereDoesntHave` is more readable. I will choose `whereDoesntHave`.
[image: whereDoesntHave and leftjoin]

3)  To include users that **blocked the specified** `user ($id)`, to use `whereHas` blockedUsers like this:

```php
public function scopeWhoBlocked($query, $id)
{
    return $query->whereHas('blockedUsers', function($q) use ($id) {
                $q->where('ignore_lists.blocked_user_id', $id);
           });
}

// better performance: however, when you apply another where condition, you need to specify the table name ->where('users.verified', 1)
public function scopeWhoBlocked($query, $id)
{
    return $query->join('ignore_lists', function($q) use ($id) {
               $q->on('ignore_lists.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->where('ignore_lists.blocked_user_id', $id);
           })->select('users.*')->distinct();
}
```

4) To include users that **did not block** the specified `user ($id)`, use `whereDoesntHave` for blockedByUsers:

```php
public function scopeWhoDidNotBlock($query, $id)
{
    return $query->whereDoesntHave('blockedUsers', function($q) use ($id) {
                $q->where('ignore_lists.blocked_user_id', $id);
           });
}
```

PS: Remember to add index on `foreign_key` for `ignore_lists` table.

Comment: `scopeAreBlockedBy` and `scopeWhoBlocked` are the same. I think in `scopeAreBlockedBy` it should be `select('blocked_user_id')` instead of `select('user_id')` and also `where('user_id', $id)` instead of `where('blocked_user_id', $id)`. Also it's missing `use ($id)` in first one. Anyway, I'll test these tomorrow (and will wait a few days until I accept the correct answer/add bounty :))
Thanks!

Comment: @PeraMika I have change my answer to whereHas and whereDoesntHave, which is more readable

Comment: I just tested the first one (`scopeAreBlockedBy`) and it it wrong. Instead of `where('users.id', $id)` it should be `where('ignore_lists.user_id', $id)`. 
It seems that the other examples have the similar mistake... 
Can you please correct / double check your answer?

Comment: Also, the "join" version of the first one doesn't seem to work, getting `Unknown column 'ignore_lists' in 'on clause' ` ...

Comment: @PeraMika sorry for that syntax error. I have fix it.

Comment: @PeraMika I add some mysql performance analysis for these queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas` and [Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) `whereDoesntHave` query builder functions to build your result queries.

I have included each query generated SQL code and query time in milliseconds tested on a dual Xeon dedicated server on a table that has 1000 users.

We don't want to get current user in the results when querying with `areNotBlockedBy` and `whoDidNotBlock`, so these functions will exclude the user with `$id`.

1. To include users that **are** blocked by the specified user (`$id`):

   ```
   /**
    * Scope a query to only include users that are blocked by the specified user.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
    * @param $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
    */
   public function scopeAreBlockedBy($query, $id)
   {
       return User::whereHas('blockedByUsers', function($q) use($id) {
           $q->where('user_id', $id);
       });
   }
   ```

   Executing:

   ```
   User::areBlockedBy(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();
   ```

   Will generate the following SQL:

   ```sql
   -- Showing rows 0 - 3 (4 total, Query took 0.0006 seconds.)
   select * from `users` where exists (select * from `users` as `laravel_reserved_9` inner join `ignore_lists` on `laravel_reserved_9`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`blocked_user_id` and `user_id` = ?) and `verified` = ?
   ```
2. To include users that are **not** blocked by the specified user (`$id`):

   ```
   /**
    * Scope a query to only include users that are not blocked by the specified user.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
    * @param $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
    */
   public function scopeAreNotBlockedBy($query, $id)
   {
       // It will exclude the user with $id
       return User::where('id', '!=', $id)
           ->whereDoesntHave('blockedByUsers', function($q) use($id) {
               $q->where('user_id', $id);
           });
   }
   ```

   Executing:

   ```
   User::areNotBlockedBy(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();
   ```

   Will generate the following SQL:

   ```sql
   -- Showing rows 0 - 24 (990 total, Query took 0.0005 seconds.)
   select * from `users` where `id` != ? and not exists (select * from `users` as `laravel_reserved_0` inner join `ignore_lists` on `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`blocked_user_id` and `user_id` = ?) and `verified` = ?
   ```
3. To include users that **blocked** the specified user (`$id`):

   ```
   /**
    * Scope a query to only include users that blocked the specified user.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
    * @param $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
    */
   public function scopeWhoBlocked($query, $id)
   {
       return User::whereHas('blockedUsers', function($q) use($id) {
           $q->where('blocked_user_id', $id);
       });
   }
   ```

   Executing:

   ```
   User::whoBlocked(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();
   ```

   Will generate the following SQL:

   ```sql
   -- Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.0004 seconds.)
   select * from `users` where exists (select * from `users` as `laravel_reserved_12` inner join `ignore_lists` on `laravel_reserved_12`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`blocked_user_id` where `users`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`user_id` and `blocked_user_id` = ?) and `verified` = ?
   ```
4. To include users that **did not block** the specified user (`$id`):

   ```
   /**
    * Scope a query to only include users that did not block the specified user.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
    * @param $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
    */
   public function scopeWhoDidNotBlock($query, $id)
   {
       // It will exclude the user with $id
       return User::where('id', '!=', $id)
           ->whereDoesntHave('blockedUsers', function($q) use($id) {
               $q->where('blocked_user_id', $id);
           });
   }
   ```

   Executing:

   ```
   User::whoDidNotBlock(auth()->id())->where('verified', 1)->get();
   ```

   Will generate the following SQL:

   ```sql
   -- Showing rows 0 - 24 (992 total, Query took 0.0004 seconds.)
   select * from `users` where `id` != ? and not exists (select * from `users` as `laravel_reserved_1` inner join `ignore_lists` on `laravel_reserved_1`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`blocked_user_id` where `users`.`id` = `ignore_lists`.`user_id` and `blocked_user_id` = ?) and `verified` = ?
   ```